# Number of iterations until incremental sum = x

Tags: arithmetic

It costs \$50 for 1 token
each token I buy increases the cost by \$50
how many tokens can I buy if I have \$10,000?

I'm trying to code a formula for this but can't figure it out without just using a loop.

Comment: How much does token number $k$ cost?

Comment: If you pretend to be a different person each time you buy a token, you can buy 200 of them. Or give 199 of your closest friends 50 dollars each to buy a token for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $a_1=50$. Then 
$$a_2=a_1+50, a_3=a_2+ 50 ,...$$
 or else
$$a_n=a_1+(n-1)50=50+(n-1)50=50n$$
Then the sum of the first n numbers of the sequence is:
$$S=a_1+a_2+a_3+...+a_n=50+2\cdot 50+ 3\cdot 50+ ...+ 50n=50(1+2+3+...+n)=50\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=25n(n+1)$$

So in our problem:
$$S=10000\Rightarrow 25n(n+1)=10000\Rightarrow n^2 +n= 400 \Rightarrow n^2+n-400=0$$
Which has no natural numbers as root. So from here you must find a final cost that is very near to 10000 and give integer roots to the above equation.

Comment: OK that helps. I've come up with this code which I believe utilizes your solution as best I can. It works sub-second up to 100 Quintillion dollars which is orders of magnitude beyond what I need it for.

int availableCash = 10000, cost = 50;
int n = (int)(Math.Sqrt(availableCash / 50.0d) * 1.4);
while (cost <= availableCash)
cost = (int)(Math.Pow(++n, 2) + n) * 25;
response = "Buy " + (n - 1) + " Tokens";

Thanks!